# OrderBy math column in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, html, angularjs-orderby

I have a table like this:

`<tr ng-repeat="x in data | orderBy:xxxx">
    <td>{{ x.name}}</td>
    <td>{{ x.price * x.count }}</td>
</tr>`

How can I order this table row by {{ x.price * x.count }} column.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`orderBy` cab accept not only a value, but a function as well. In order to use it in your case, add a function to your scope:

```
$scope.calculateOrder = function(item) {
    return item.price * item.count;
};
```

And then you can use this function in your filter:

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in data | orderBy:calculateOrder">
```

You can read more about [orderBy on Angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy)

Answer (score 1):

You can do the calculation inline.

```
orderBy: 'price * count'
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9ybaxjnt/)